# Can this algebraic equation become simpler?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

We define $\mathbf A = \mathbf K_1 \mathbf K_2 ... \mathbf K_n$ where $\mathbf K_i$ is a sequence of $2 \times 2$ matrices. Using determinant property, the following algebraic equation:
$$\det(\mathbf A) = 0$$
can be simplified as:
$$\det(\mathbf A) = \prod_{i=1}^n \det(\mathbf K_i) = 0$$
and conclude that:
$$\det(\mathbf K_1) = 0 \lor \det(\mathbf K_2) = 0 \lor ... \lor \det(\mathbf K_n) = 0$$

Now consider the case where an Identity matrix is subtracted:
$$\det(\mathbf A-\mathbf I)=0$$
I could simplify the equation as follows:
$$ \det(\mathbf A - \mathbf I) = \det(\mathbf A) - trace(\mathbf A) + 1=0$$
However, I am wondering that this equation can be further simplified. I think, since the above is similar to $\det(\mathbf  A-\lambda \mathbf I)=0$, the characteristic equation of linear eigen-value problems; there has to be something related.

Comment: You cannot conclude that all of the individual determinants are equal to zero, only that at least one of them is.

Comment: @Nirai Yes, I meant each one of them at a time, not all together. Thank you for being meticulous.

Comment: You also have that $\det(A-I)=(\lambda_1-1)(\lambda_2-1)$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @KBS It is a very good hint, but the problem is that we cant express the eigenvalues of product of a set of matrices in terms of them directly. can we?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi No unless they commute, for instance. Your problem is not solvable in general.

Comment: @KBS is there any trick so we can make them commute? I read the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi no there is no such trick.

Comment: @KBS hello again, I've noticed that my $\mathbf K_i$ matrices can be chosen in a way that they all have identical set of eigenvalues but with different eigenvectors. I know if the eigenvectors were the same, we could simply multiply the eigenvalues. Can this help?

Comment: @HoseinJavanmardi Unfortunately, only the eigenvectors matter in multiplication.